# GoogleMapSDK hierarchy when trying to add a button on it

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, uibutton, layer

I'm trying to add a button in front of the GoogleMap view. The problem is between the time where the map has been initialized and when the design of the map appear two extra layer comes and hides my button.

Screen of the hierarchy (don't have the reputation in order to embed a image)

[image: https://puu.sh/w9AYo/aebab63b5f.png]

I tried to move the button view in front of GMSMapView but it didn't work.